# Where can I find the right GPU driver for a MSI M670 notebook runnig Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I'm searching for the right GPU driver for a MSI M670 notebook runnig Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I can't find it. I set the Notebook up for a friend an it worked fine after I installed the close-sourced drivers that Ubuntu provided, but now the notebook is frozen after login just as before the fix. According to lspci the GPU is a Geforce Go 6100. I followed [this](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/) fix, but the driver seems to be wrong, I get "You don’t appear to have nvidia GPU supported by 331.38 driver installed in this system.". 
I'm out of ideas and would be very thankful for any help. :(

Comment: You could try the xorg-edgers ppa to see about installing drivers for the 6100.  http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/  A word of warning though, read here about removing the PPA before upgrading your OS on your system:  http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers

Comment: Maybe I try that, thanks. The thing is I don't see the Geforce Go 6100 listed as supported. Does it have another name on the list?

Comment: I looked for the Go 6100 everywhere, and I can't seem to find that specific driver.  I do see that the 304.125 driver supports the GeForce 6100 and 6150LE cards.  This link shows the Go 6100 is supported, so my guess would be that it is supported under the 304.125 driver.  http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-9746/README/appendix-a.html

Comment: Ah HA!  I found it on this list:  http://www.nvidia.com/object/io_32667.html  It shows it supported under the 304.xx driver.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I feel I might actually solve this, I had lost all hope. :D So the way I would install the driver via the PPA would be "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa", "sudo apt-get update", "sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-340", right? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I haven't installed something from PPA for a a long time.

Comment: After the repository is setup and the apt-get update is done, to install that driver would be `sudo apt-get install nvidia-304`.

Comment: I'm writing this up as an answer for you.

Comment: You're welcome.   One other thing we could try is to create a xorg.conf file.  When it comes up to that blank screen with the mouse moving, press CTRL+ALT+F2, and it should kick you to a full terminal.  Log in, then type in `sudo nvidia-xconfig`.  Your hardware might need one like my system does.  The xorg.conf file goes into the `/etc/X11/` folder.  Might be worth a shot.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F2 was how I did the whole thing, maybe that's the problem somehow? Did "sudo nvidia-xconfig" and got "WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file New x configuration file was written to /etc/X11/xorg.conf". No change (I noticed if i leave the black screen up for a really long time, it brings me back to the login screen, but i don't think that has something to do with it. There was a message, but it was up to short to read). Did i do something wrong? Thanks again. ;-)

Comment: No, the CTRL+ALT+F2 is a tty to work in, so that's not the problem.  I use it all the time to fix boot problems, etc.  Try typing in `dmesg | less` so it gives you screen by screen, and see if you can't see any driver failures during the bootup.  `dmesg` should show you your boot logs.  Also try typing in `grep -i failed /var/log/boot.log` and see if anything failed during boot.

Comment: Lol, I'm going to be honest, I couldn't make out what 30% of all the stuff "dmesg | less" gave me meant. There might be  something in there, but I'm sure as hell arn't smart enough to find it. "rep -i failed /var/log/boot.log" gave me nothing, so I guess nothing failed. I think I will try a fresh install with another distro now, maybe Fedora, the live CD  worked fine. Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: No problem for being patient here.  I have a laptop that I bought brand new back in 2006, and it barely runs Ubuntu 14.04.  It runs the smaller distros like Lubuntu, which is a light-weight version.  Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE.  Try any of those maybe.  Check here:  http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours  Good luck on your way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this list [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/io_32667.html), your video card is supported under the NVIDIA-304.xx driver.

To install this driver, first add the `xorg-edgers` ppa from a terminal window type in:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

then update the repositories by typing in the next line:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then to install the 304.xx driver, type in the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

**NOTE:** the important notices that are found [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers) recommend that you purge the ppa before you do a `dist-upgrade` to your Ubuntu installation, or it breaks your OS.

**From the xorg-edgers PPA**

***Be sure to revert this PPA before doing a release upgrade or the upgrade will not succeed. To revert to official packages, install the ppa-purge package and run "sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers".***